# MySQL binlogs to BigQuery, what's a good design for replication?

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-pubsub, change-data-capture

In order to run (almost real time) data analysis, we started streaming binlogs from our production MariaDb database (update, insert, alter, create etc ... statements) to a Pub/Sub topic on GCP.
There are quite a few tables from production that we would like to have back in BigQuery, how would you replicate those tables:

- stream the binlog messages from table A to a staging partitioned BQ table "staging_A" with a flexible struct schema + having a Airflow DAG that periodically deduplicates "staging_A" to "prod_A" executing a BQ statement (row_number + MERGE statement I guess).
- convert binlog messages to INSERT/UPDATE statements to have some kind of direct replication and avoid using a (slow) Airflow DAG ..
- any other option?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: How the data in BigQuery will be consumed? To provide "what" in real time?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere Mainly consumed by numerous dashboards (we use Metabase for BI). Thanks for any insights you may have

Comment: Ok, my question was: does it really in real-time or in small batch (every 15 minutes for example) is acceptable? In addition, how many events to you have per day/minute/seconds?

Comment: 15-minute batches would be good enough for bi. We've got around 500 events per second (updates and inserts).

Comment: Do you want to apply the insert/update as SQL command? Or will you parse the content of bin log to load (batch or stream) the data?

Comment: Isn't it the question I'm asking in my post? The binlogs are already "formatted", i.e. i have all fields before and all fields after for update statements. I looks to be better design to stream them to staging tables and have some kind of deduplicating pipeline orchestrated by Airflow that runs every 15 minutes. Would you say so?

Comment: What do you save in BigQuery at first? Do you have your original data saved in a BigQuery table?

Comment: @rmesteves These are still pending questions. For now we have a pub/sub with binlogs from the MariaDb database, and we want clean tables on BigQuery!

Comment: Do you have any data in BigQuery?

Comment: Well not yet, that's what we're aiming at!

Comment: Is having a script in Python that read the new data and wrtie to BigQuery an option for you?

Comment: Yes of course !

Comment: @MissouPower for your option 1 which you merge CDC data from "staging_A" to "prod_A", do you periodically remove merged data in "staging_A" to save computation of merging?

Comment: Hi @WaiKiat, we don't, our staging_A is partitionned so that the MERGE statement does not scan all rows but only recent rows.  On the other hand, the deduplicated table (much smaller table) will have most of its rows scanned during the MERGE: that's mainly true for "dimension" tables but not for "transactional" tables (which are partitionned on a "created_at" field from the original prod table ). Indeed, recently ingested data is usually recent INSERTS in the prod table, so partitionning still works during the MERGE.

Comment: @MissouPower Thanks for your reply! Yea, we use 1. table to stage all CDC data, 2. partition table to stage *recent* CDC data, and perform MERGE using 2 instead. Thanks for your sharing.